# Call all class styles into one class using SCSS or LESS

Tags: html, css, sass, less

This bothers me a while. I want to make a class that contains a specific group of classes (If this is to be possible). Like this:

```
.main_class {
  //Contains multiple class css
  class_one_css
  class_two_css
  class_three_css
}
```

Then you could call it like this

```
<input type="text" class="main_class"/>
```

Instead of calling multiple classes like this

```
<input type="text" class="class_one class_two class_three"/>
```

Hope to get an answer soon. Thank you.

Comment: In Sass, use `extend`: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extending_complex_selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using LESS..
[Sample pen](http://codepen.io/YaserAliPeedikakkal/pen/WxypEm)

LESS css

```
.class_one {
    background: #c0c0c0;
  }
.class_two {
    width: 200px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
 }
 .class_three {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
 }

 .main_class {
    .class_one ();
    .class_two ();
    .class_three ();
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="main_class">
   Your text goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Good one. Thanks (High Five!)

Answer (score 2):

Using LESS you can do just that

```
.main_class {
  //Contains multiple class css
  .class_one_css;
  .class_two_css;
  .class_three_css;
}
```

Try it here: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler